# Search with LIKE statement in SQLite, with Python and the Tkinter library

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, python-3.9

I am developing a project, and when it comes to adding a search engine, it does not work correctly, I write something in it and it throws me the following sqlite3 error.

ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of links supplied. The current statement uses 0 and X is provided.

I have declared the search function, and it is assigned to the search button, if I change something in the query it goes blank without yielding any apparent results after clicking on the search button and never gets to show me what it indicates in the search box. Honestly, I have exhausted all my knowledge and got stuck in this step. I would greatly appreciate the help and if you can correctly explain to me where I was failing to move forward. I need the search to update the same treeview

I share my code.

Best regards.

the comment lines below the search function are the other options I was trying

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import csv
import os
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3



class Stock:
 # propiedades de la conexion a base de datos---
db_name = 'database.db'

def __init__(self, window):

    # Inicializacion 
    self.Ventana_Principal = window
    self.Ventana_Principal.title('Software Prueba')

    # Contenedor de Entrada de datos
    frame = LabelFrame(self.Ventana_Principal, text = 'Productos--')
    frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 30, padx = 30, pady = 30)

    # Entrada de Clave
    Label(frame, text = 'Clave: ').grid(row = 1, column = 0)
    self.Clave = Entry(frame)
    self.Clave.focus()
    self.Clave.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

    # Entrada de Unidad
    Label(frame, text = 'Unidad: ').grid(row = 2, column = 0)
    self.Unidad = Entry(frame)
    self.Unidad.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

    # Entrada de Nombre Producto
    Label(frame, text = 'Nombre: ').grid(row = 3, column = 0)
    self.Nombre = Entry(frame)
    self.Nombre.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

    # Entrada de Cantidad
    Label(frame, text = 'Cantidad: ').grid(row = 1, column = 2)
    self.Cantidad = Entry(frame)
    self.Cantidad.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

    # Entrada de Precio Compra
    Label(frame, text = 'Precio Compra: ').grid(row = 2, column = 2)
    self.PrecioCompra = Entry(frame)
    self.PrecioCompra.grid(row = 2, column = 3)

    # Entrada de Precio Venta
    Label(frame, text = 'Precio Venta: ').grid(row = 3, column = 2)
    self.PrecioVenta = Entry(frame)
    self.PrecioVenta.grid(row = 3, column = 3)


    # Boton Agregar Producto - Importar Archivo
    ttk.Button(frame, text = 'Guardar Producto', command = self.agregar_productos).grid(row = 10, columnspan = 5, sticky = W + E)
    

    #Seccion de Busqueda
    Label(frame, text = 'Buscar: ').grid(row = 4, column = 0)
    self.Buscador = Entry(frame, textvariable = StringVar())
    self.Buscador.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
    Button(frame, text = "Buscar Producto", command = self.buscar_registro).grid(row = 4, column = 2)
    

    # Mensajes de Salida 
    self.mensaje = Label(text = '', fg = 'red')
    self.mensaje.grid(row = 3, column = 5, columnspan = 5, sticky = W + E)

    # Tabla
    self.tabla = ttk.Treeview(height = 10, columns = ('#1','#2','#3','#4'))
    self.tabla.grid(row = 4, column = 5, columnspan = 5)
    self.tabla.heading('#0', text = 'Codigo/Clave', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tabla.heading('#1', text = 'Producto', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tabla.heading('#2', text = 'Cantidad', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tabla.heading('#3', text = 'Precio Compra', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tabla.heading('#4', text = 'Precio Venta', anchor = CENTER)
   
    # Botones Eliminar - Editar - Importar 
    ttk.Button(text = 'Editar', command = self.editar_productos).grid(row = 5, column = 5, sticky = W + E)
    ttk.Button(text = 'Eliminar', command = self.eliminar_productos).grid(row = 5, column = 9, sticky = W + E)
    ttk.Button(text = 'Importar Archivo', command = self.importar_csv).grid(row = 1, column = 7, sticky = W + E)
    ttk.Button(text = 'Exportar Archivo', command = self.exportar_csv).grid(row = 2, column = 7, sticky = W + E)
    
    # Ordenando las filas
    self.ordenar_productos()

# Funcion a ejecutar en la base de datos --Querys--
def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result

# Leer Tabla de base de datos
def ordenar_productos(self):
    # Limpiar Tabla 
    records = self.tabla.get_children()
    for element in records:
        self.tabla.delete(element)
    # Seleccionar datos
    query = 'SELECT * FROM Productos ORDER BY Clave DESC'
    db_rows = self.run_query(query)
    # Acomodar datos
    for row in db_rows:
        self.tabla.insert('', 0, text = row[1], values = row[3:7])


def buscar_registro(self):
    self.buscar = self.Buscador.get()
    query = "SELECT Nombre FROM Productos WHERE Nombre LIKE '%"+self.buscar+"%' ORDER BY Nombre DESC"   #"SELECT Nombre FROM Productos WHERE Nombre LIKE '%"+self.Buscador.get()+"%' ORDER BY Nombre DESC"
    parameters = (self.buscar)   
    self.run_query(query, parameters)
    self.ordenar_productos()
    
    #palabra = self.Buscador.get()
    #query = "SELECT Nombre FROM Productos WHERE Nombre LIKE '%"+self.buscar+"%' ORDER BY Nombre DESC"
    #parameters = (self.buscar)   
    #self.run_query(query, parameters).fetchall()
    #self.ordenar_productos()



# Validacion de datos ingresados por el usuario
def validacion(self):
    return len(self.Clave.get()) != 0 and len(self.Nombre.get()) != 0 and len(self.Cantidad.get()) != 0 and len(self.PrecioCompra.get()) != 0 and len(self.PrecioVenta.get()) != 0

# Funcion Agregar Productos
def agregar_productos(self):
    if self.validacion():
        query = 'INSERT INTO Productos VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
        parameters =  (self.Clave.get(), self.Unidad.get(), self.Nombre.get(), self.Cantidad.get(), self.PrecioCompra.get(), self.PrecioVenta.get())
        self.run_query(query, parameters)
        self.mensaje['text'] = 'Producto {} Se Agrego Correctamente'.format(self.Nombre.get())
        self.Clave.delete(0, END)
        self.Unidad.delete(0, END)
        self.Nombre.delete(0, END)
        self.Cantidad.delete(0, END)
        self.PrecioCompra.delete(0, END)
        self.PrecioVenta.delete(0, END)
    else:
        self.mensaje['text'] = 'Los Campos no Pueden estar Vacios'
    self.ordenar_productos()
    
# Funcion de Eliminar
def eliminar_productos(self):
    self.mensaje['text'] = ''
    try:
       self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())['values'][0]
    except IndexError as e:
        self.mensaje['text'] = 'Debe Seleccionar un Registro'
        return
    self.mensaje['text'] = ''
    nombre = self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())['text']
    query = 'DELETE FROM Productos WHERE Clave = ?'
    self.run_query(query, (nombre, ))
    self.mensaje['text'] = 'Registro {} Eliminado'.format(nombre)
    self.ordenar_productos()


# Funcion de Edicion
def editar_productos(self):
    self.mensaje['text'] = ''
    try:
        self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())['values'][0]
    except IndexError as e:
        self.mensaje['text'] = 'Debe Seleccionar un Registro'
        return
    Nombre_Anterior = self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())['values'][0]
    Cantidad_Anterior = self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())['values'][1]
    Precio_Anterior_Compra = self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())['values'][2]
    Precio_Anterior_Venta = self.tabla.item(self.tabla.selection())['values'][3]
    self.Ventana_Edicion = Toplevel()
    self.Ventana_Edicion.title ('Editar Producto')
    
    # Nombre Anterior
    Label(self.Ventana_Edicion, text = 'Nombre Anterior:').grid(row = 0, column = 1)
    Entry(self.Ventana_Edicion, textvariable = StringVar(self.Ventana_Edicion, value = Nombre_Anterior), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 0, column = 2)
    
    # Nuevo Nombre
    Label(self.Ventana_Edicion, text = 'Nuevo Nombre:').grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    Nuevo_Nombre = Entry(self.Ventana_Edicion)
    Nuevo_Nombre.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

     # Cantidad Anterior 
    Label(self.Ventana_Edicion, text = 'Stock Anterior:').grid(row = 2, column = 1)
    Entry(self.Ventana_Edicion, textvariable = StringVar(self.Ventana_Edicion, value = Cantidad_Anterior), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 2, column = 2)
    
    # Nueva Cantidad
    Label(self.Ventana_Edicion, text = 'Nuevo Stock:').grid(row = 3, column = 1)
    Nueva_Cantidad= Entry(self.Ventana_Edicion)
    Nueva_Cantidad.grid(row = 3, column = 2)

    # Precio Compra Anterior
    Label(self.Ventana_Edicion, text = 'Precio Compra Anterior :').grid(row = 0, column = 3)
    Entry(self.Ventana_Edicion, textvariable = StringVar(self.Ventana_Edicion, value = Precio_Anterior_Compra), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 0, column = 4)
    
    # Nuevo Precio de Compra
    Label(self.Ventana_Edicion, text = 'Nuevo Precio Compra:').grid(row = 1, column = 3)
    Nuevo_Precio_Compra= Entry(self.Ventana_Edicion)
    Nuevo_Precio_Compra.grid(row = 1, column = 4)

    # Precio Venta Anterior 
    Label(self.Ventana_Edicion, text = 'Precio Venta Anterior:').grid(row = 2, column = 3)
    Entry(self.Ventana_Edicion, textvariable = StringVar(self.Ventana_Edicion, value = Precio_Anterior_Venta), state = 'readonly').grid(row = 2, column = 4)
    
    # Nuevo Precio de Venta
    Label(self.Ventana_Edicion, text = 'Nuevo Precio Venta:').grid(row = 3, column = 3)
    Nuevo_Precio_Venta= Entry(self.Ventana_Edicion)
    Nuevo_Precio_Venta.grid(row = 3, column = 4)

    # Boton Actualizar
    Button(self.Ventana_Edicion, text = 'Actualizar', command = lambda: self.editar_registros(Nuevo_Nombre.get(), Nombre_Anterior, Nueva_Cantidad.get(), Cantidad_Anterior, Nuevo_Precio_Compra.get(), Precio_Anterior_Compra, Nuevo_Precio_Venta.get(), Precio_Anterior_Venta)).grid(row = 8, columnspan = 5, sticky = W + E)
    self.Ventana_Edicion.mainloop()

# funcion de edicion
def editar_registros(self, Nuevo_Nombre, Nombre_Anterior, Nueva_Cantidad, Cantidad_Anterior, Nuevo_Precio_Compra, Precio_Anterior_Compra, Nuevo_Precio_Venta, Precio_Anterior_Venta):
    query = 'UPDATE Productos SET Nombre = ?, Cantidad = ?, PrecioCompra = ?, PrecioVenta = ? WHERE Nombre = ? AND Cantidad = ? AND PrecioCompra = ? AND PrecioVenta = ?'  
    parameters = (Nuevo_Nombre, Nueva_Cantidad, Nuevo_Precio_Compra, Nuevo_Precio_Venta, Nombre_Anterior, Cantidad_Anterior, Precio_Anterior_Compra, Precio_Anterior_Venta)
    self.run_query(query, parameters)
    self.Ventana_Edicion.destroy()
    self.mensaje['text'] = 'Registro {} fue Actualizado Correctamente'.format(Nuevo_Nombre)
    self.ordenar_productos()



if __name__ == '__main__':
window = Tk()
application = Stock(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `LIKE '%"+self.buscar+"%'`, but I expect you wanted those `%%` *inside* the double quotes.

Also, don't construct queries as strings like this. Instead, use `?` in the query and pass parameters to allow SQLite to make the substition safely:

```py
    query = "SELECT Nombre FROM Productos WHERE Nombre LIKE ? ORDER BY Nombre DESC"
    self.run_query(query, (f'%{self.buscar}%',))
```

If you don't like f-strings for some reason:

```py
    self.run_query(query, ('%' + self.buscar + '%',))
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much, add an information text to see what I did and I manage to find the search, anyway I still have problems to update the tree view with the search data.

Comment: This is likely because after running the query, you don't do anything with the result that `run_query()` returns, but you just call `self.ordenar_productos()`, which then proceeds to run another query. However, we can't debug your program step by step in the comments. Please have a look at what you think the problem is and if you have a specific issue, post a new question about that.